# Showing all windows in Windows 10 on program switch like on Mac

Tags: windows, windows-10

On Mac when I click an app in the Dock or `Cmd + tab` to another app, it brings all of the app's windows to the front.

On Window when I click a program in the Taskbar or `Windows Key + tab` then it makes me select specific windows within the program to bring to the front. This is a major pain if I need to get all of my windows back to the front again for a single program if I have numerous windows in that program carefully arranged for my use of that program. I have to do them one by one until all are to the front.

How do I make all of my Windows for a single program come to the front the moment I switch back to that program?

Comment: The changes to Windows 11 likely will satisfy the requirements you describe.  However, Windows isn't macOS, so there will be differences between the two operating systems that cannot be solved without third-party applications.

Answer (score -2):

I will continue to try an search for a better solution that is more similar to the way a Mac operates...

But a simple, slightly annoying solution for now, is when you press `Windows Key + Tab` and select the new app you would like to switch to, press `Windows Key + D` **twice** to bring up all of the relevant windows for that application. The first time you press `Windows Key + D`, it will minimize everything, and the second time is will bring up all of the relevant windows for whichever application you previously were on before the first time you press it.

Although this isn't quite as elegant as the way a Mac does it, hopefully, it will save you some time and be more efficient than manually opening every window for that application. The great thing is this saves the configuration of the windows. So, if two of the windows were in split screen previously, it will bring them to the front in the same split screen configuration.

Feel free to try it out and let me know how it goes and if you have any questions.

Comment: `Althought this isn't quite as elegant as the way a Mac does it` is a matter of opinion (and misspelled).  I like the way Windows manages tasks.  It is a matter of what you are used to.

Comment: I wasn't putting down the way Windows manages tasks, I was simply trying to explain the solution in terms that @EcomEvo would appreciate. On a Mac, when you select the app, all the windows of that app come to the front. On Windows, I found a way to do that, but it takes two extra keyboard shortcuts. This is not as elegant because it requires more steps. But that isn't to say Windows handles tasks poorly, just differently, and in this case requiring a few more steps. Like Ramhound mentioned, this feature will be included in Windows 11, so clearly Windows recognized they needed to add it.